# Cross join with Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

I'm trying to learn some F# and Deedle by analyzing my electricity costs.

Suppose I have two frames, one containing my electricity usage:

```fs
let consumptionsByYear = 
  [ (2019, "Total", 500); (2019, "Day", 200); (2019, "Night", 300);
    (2020, "Total", 600); (2020, "Day", 250); (2020, "Night", 350) ]
  |> Frame.ofValues
```

```
        Total Day Night 
2019 -> 500   200 300   
2020 -> 600   250 350
```

The other contains two plans with different pricing structure (either a flat fee or fee varying based on the time of the day):

```fs
let prices = 
  [ ("Plan A", "Base fee", 50); ("Plan A", "Fixed price", 3); ("Plan A", "Day price", 0); ("Plan A", "Night price", 0);
    ("Plan B", "Base fee", 40); ("Plan B", "Fixed price", 0); ("Plan B", "Day price", 5); ("Plan B", "Night price", 2) ]
  |> Frame.ofValues
```

```
          Base fee Fixed price Day price Night price 
Plan A -> 50       3           0         0           
Plan B -> 40       0           5         2
```

Previously I have solved this in SQL using a cross join and in Excel using nested joins. To copy those, I found `Frame.mapRows`, but constructing the expected output seems very tedious using it:

```fs
let costs = consumptionsByYear
            |> Frame.mapRows (fun _year cols ->
                ["Total price" => (prices?``Base fee``
                    + (prices?``Fixed price`` |> Series.mapValues ((*) (cols.GetAs<float>("Total"))))
                    + (prices?``Day price`` |> Series.mapValues ((*) (cols.GetAs<float>("Day"))))
                    + (prices?``Night price`` |> Series.mapValues ((*) (cols.GetAs<float>("Night"))))
                    )]
                |> Frame.ofColumns)
            |> Frame.unnest
```

```
               Total price 
2019 Plan A -> 1550        
     Plan B -> 1640        
2020 Plan A -> 1850        
     Plan B -> 1990
```

Is there a better way or even small improvements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Deedle expert, but I think this is basically:

- A dot product of two matrices: `consumptionsByYear` and the periodic day/night prices,
- Followed by the addition of the constant base prices.

In other words:

```
 consumptionsByYear      periodicPrices               basePrices
 -------------------     ------------------------     ---------------------------
|         Day Night |   |          Plan A Plan B |   |             Plan A Plan B |
| 2019 -> 200 300   | * | Day   -> 3      5      | + | Base fee -> 50     40     |
| 2020 -> 250 350   |   | Night -> 3      2      |    ---------------------------
 -------------------     ------------------------
```

With that approach in mind, here's how I would do it:

```ml
open Deedle
open Deedle.Math

let consumptionsByYear = 
    [ (2019, "Day", 200); (2019, "Night", 300)
      (2020, "Day", 250); (2020, "Night", 350) ]
    |> Frame.ofValues

let basePrices =
    [ ("Plan A", "Base fee", 50)
      ("Plan B", "Base fee", 40) ]
    |> Frame.ofValues
    |> Frame.transpose

let periodicPrices =
    [ ("Plan A", "Day", 3); ("Plan A", "Night", 3)
      ("Plan B", "Day", 5); ("Plan B", "Night", 2) ]
    |> Frame.ofValues
    |> Frame.transpose

// repeat the base prices for each year
let basePricesExpanded =
    let row = basePrices.Rows.["Base fee"]
    consumptionsByYear
        |> Frame.mapRowValues (fun _ -> row)
        |> Frame.ofRows

let result =
    Matrix.dot(consumptionsByYear, periodicPrices) + basePricesExpanded
result.Print()
```

Output is:

```
        Plan A Plan B
2019 -> 1550   1640
2020 -> 1850   1990
```

A few changes I made for simplicity:

- `consumptionsByYear`

  - I mapped the years from integers to strings in order to make the matrices compatible.
  - I removed the `Total` column, since it can be derived from the other two.
- `prices`

  - I broke this into two separate frames: one for the periodic prices and another for the base prices, and then transposed them to enable matrix multiplication.
  - I changed `Day price` to `Day` and `Night price` to `Night` to make the matrices compatible.
  - I got rid of the `Fixed price` column, since it can be represented in the `Day` and `Night` columns.

Update: As of [Deedle 2.4.2](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/issues/536), it is no longer necessary to map the years to strings. I've modified my solution accordingly.

Comment: Great, thanks! `Frame.transpose` and `Deedle.Math` are exactly what I was looking for.

Adding a third periodic pricing structure with prices for winter business (Mon-Sat) days and other season (Sundays, winter nights, summer), seems to be easily handled with dividing the data into `WinterBusinessDay,DayOther,Night`. I'm starting to see the benefits of Deedle.